# Why does downgrading RPM not remove newer version (both versions are installed)?

Tags: rpm, yum

I am attempting to downgrade a RPM via the following commands:

```
# RPM install
sudo rpm -Uvh --oldpackage rpm-name-oldversion

# Yum install
sudo yum --nogpgcheck downgrade  localinstall rpm-name-oldversion
```

However both RPMs are shown as installed which doesn't make sense to me.

Note: I have built these RPMs myself and are on a CentOS/Redhat machines.

**Update 1: debugging turned on**

(I started from scratch by deleting all of the package)

#### Install new version first

```
sudo yum localinstall my-package-1.5.5-1.x86_64.rpm
```

#### Check installed

```
rpm -qa | grep my-package
my-package-1.5.5-1
```

#### Downgrade

```
yum --nogpgcheck downgrade localinstall -d10 my-package-1.5.3-1.x86_64.rpm
```

#### Output trimmed

```
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Member: my-package.x86_64 0-1.5.3-1 - u
Adding Package my-package-1.5.3-1.x86_64 in mode u
Member: my-package.x86_64 0-1.5.5-1 - e
Removing Package my-package-1.5.5-1.x86_64
rpm_check_debug time: 0.066
Running Transaction Test
Member: my-package.x86_64 0-1.5.3-1 - u
Adding Package my-package-1.5.3-1.x86_64 in mode u
Member: my-package.x86_64 0-1.5.5-1 - e
Removing Package my-package-1.5.5-1.x86_64
Finished Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Transaction Test time: 0.275
Member: my-package.x86_64 0-1.5.3-1 - u
Adding Package my-package-1.5.3-1.x86_64 in mode u
Member: my-package.x86_64 0-1.5.5-1 - e
Removing Package my-package-1.5.5-1.x86_64

Removed:
  my-package.x86_64 0:1.5.5-1                                                                                                                

Installed:
  my-package.x86_64 0:1.5.3-1                                                                                                                

Complete!
```

#### Check installed

```
rpm -qa | grep my-package
my-package-1.5.5-1
my-package-1.5.3-1
```

**Update 2: Works on another server**

I am closing this topic off as it appears to work on another server so will continue to investigate on my end.

Comment: Is `--localpackage` a valid option to `rpm`? What does rpm show for the package before the attempt exactly? What about after?

Comment: Seems like my comment has disappeared. its `--oldpackage` not `--localpackage`, error on my part.

Comment: Are the architectures of the two packages the same?

Comment: Does upping the debugging output from either rpm or yum offer any clues? `rpm -vvv` or `yum -d10`?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Will try it and report back.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Its strange. Yum tells me that its removing the latest version however its still present when I do a post check.

Comment: What does `rpm -qa --qf '%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n' my-package` output before and after?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Same result. How is that different to `rpm -qa | grep my-package`

Comment: If you get the same output running my command as yours then you didn't run mine correctly because mine should have included package architecture information and yours did not. To answer the rest of your question though compare `rpm -qa | wc -l` and `rpm -qa my-package | wc -l`. Essentially you just get rpm to do the work for you and avoid the sub-shell, pipe, and grep entirely.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I may have jumped ahead with my answer. The command you provided did indeed show the architecture which was the same for both. I am aware that if the arch is different both RPMs will be installed.

Comment: Can you run the downgrade with `-e10` also and see what you get? Also why are you using `downgrade localinstall`? Why not just `downgrade`? Does doing that change things?

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple instances of the package installed.

Try "rpm -qa | grep rpm-name" to see how many instances
of the package that you are downgrading are registered
in the rpm database.

Comment: These RPMs are installed locally, not from a repo. Before I run the downgrade command there is only one version, say version 2. After downgrading it shows me version 1 & 2.